# Can't use standard ways to change password

Tags: linux, password-recovery

It seems like the title of million internet posts, but I think this one is new. 
I login to a server `server` with a username `usrname` and a password, say 
`pas`.

Then, I try to change the password. Here things gets weird.

```
server% su
Password: pas
su: incorrect password
```

Next I try this:

```
server% passwrd
Changing password for user usrname
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

So I try this

```
server% sudo su
[sudo] password for usrname:
Sorry, try again.
```

and so, being not a root user, I'm a bit in an awe as for what to do.

Thanks!

*additional details: *
I am running this linux version :

```
Linux version 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (                                                                                        gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46 U                                                                                        TC 2013
```

Comment: [Getting an "Authentication token manipulation" error when trying to change my user password](http://askubuntu.com/q/57620)

Comment: @DavidPostill , can I do all that without (a) being root user (b) messing around with a server which is not mine?

Comment: Also, I get for `pwconv` an error of `command not found`, though `man pwconv` returns a full manual. Huh?

Answer (score 2):

When you run 'passwd' as non-root, the first prompt is for your *current* password. Once you have authenticated, it will then prompt you for a *new* password.

If you do not know your current password, you will need to contact your system administrator to have your password reset.

Comment: When I run `passwd`, it doesn't even ask for my password, just returns the `Authentication token manipuation error`. When I run `sudo passwrd`, my correct password doesn't seem to work, as I mentioned earlier.